# QGLWidget strange behaviour with QTimer update

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, gpu, qtimer

I have a small GL Renderer running inside a QGLWidget (Qt 5.7). For updating, I use a QTimer connected to update(). I've set the timer to 16 milliseconds, resulting in my renderer to take a lot of time (~30ms). Whenever I set the QTimer interval to higher values (33 ms), the rendering goes down to less than 10ms, the same time it takes when not using Qt but glfw. Timing is profiled using Nvidia Nsight.

Is this a common behaviour of Qt? Am I stalling the event pipeline? What is the proper way to render as fast as possible while using Qt?

Comment: there can be loads of issues. no code means no way to tell.

Comment: I will add code as soon as I am back at my computer